# Copy rows of data from one workbook to another based on a value being met in 1 column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a database (quotations), I want to be able to copy rows from this database where column a contains "x" into another workbook (confirmed orders).
For reference the initial workbook is quotes, and after being marked as "x" these need to copy into the other workbook which is confirmed orders.

The information to be copied is the entire row(s) & it should look the same on the confirmed orders workbook.

```
Sub ConfirmedDatabaseAdd()
 
    Const WB_PATH As String = "S:\Dott Work\Good Order 2024\Quotes\Confirmed Orders.xlsx"
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, shtDest As Workbook, i As Long

    Set srcSht = ActiveSheet

    For i = 2 To srcSht.Range("A" & srcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If srcSht.Cells(i, 1) = "x" Then
            If shtDest Is Nothing Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WB_PATH)
                Set shtDest = wb.Sheets("Orders Confirmed")
            End If
            srcSht.Cells(i, 1).Copy _
                     shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i


    If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close True

End Sub
```

The code above is throwing up a "Run-time error '13' type mismatch" and is pointing me to the name of the sheet in the confirmed orders workbook, however the sheet name matches the code so a bit stuck on what's wrong here?

Comment: `shtDest As Workbook` ---> `shtDest As Worksheet`.

Comment: Thank you! I also need the entire row after column A to copy but it's only copying column A atm? I know it's to do with this  srcSht.Cells(i, 1).Copy _

Comment: `srcSheet.Rows(i).Copy`

Comment: This copies the entire row, but need it to do the entire row after column A if possible.

Comment: `srcSheeet.Cells(i, 2).Resize(, srcSheet.Columns.Count - 1).Copy`

Comment: Syntax Error throwing up on line below now
 shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: Make sure you still have the `_` line continuation after `Copy`

Comment: Added that in, but getting a runtime error 424 for the same section of the code

Comment: The `Workbooks.Open` really should be outside the loop. You can run into issues while calling `Workbooks.Open` on an already open workbook.

Comment: The destination workbook will always be closed which is why the workbooks.open has been added in.

Comment: Sure, but you only want to call `Workbooks.Open` *once*, not in a loop.